# Trouble assigning a dynamic range to a ListBox control

Tags: excel, vba

This should be straightforward but can't get it to work. I have a button on a sheet called Master that should display a userform (named AddApplicant) when clicked. The userform contains a ListBox (named lstCourses) in which I want to display some values from a worksheet called Course Details. The Course Details worksheet is programmatically generated, but this should have no bearing, as I've set the button that launches the user form to only be enabled when this sheet is present.

When I try to click the button that displays the userform I get an application defined or object defined error.

The problem seems to be with the code that loads the range into the ListBox, as the form displays when I comment these lines of code out.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim cell As Range
Dim cellList As Range
Set cellList = Worksheets("Course Details").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))

For Each cell In cellList
    lstCourses.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell

End Sub

'Here is the code assigned to the button that launches the form
AddApplicant.Show
```

Comment: Userform is not a sheet... `Range()` has no meaning in the userform

Comment: Just noticed that Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() refers to a generic UserForm instead of referring to the one called AddApplicant. Changed that. Now the form loads - I don't get the error. But the values are not loaded in the ListBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to clean up a couple things for you on here:

```
Dim cell As Range, cellList As Range
With Worksheets("Course Details")  'added this as you have range references without sheets
    Set cellList = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In cellList
        lstCourses.AddItem cell.Value
    Next cell
End With
```

As this is run from initialize, you would have already loaded the sheet, so no need to `.show` again.

There should have been a separate button that uses a macro reading like:

```
sub uf_loader()
    AddApplicant.Show
end sub
```